# Material2 - Pagination not showing on tabs when parent in display flex

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I've already opened a bug on their GitHub page, but in the meanwhile someone has already found a workaround to this? https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8788

When using Material 2 tabs, in a parent container which has its display property set to flex, the pagination controls on the tabs are not shown. (the tabs must be enough to force the pagination to show up, of course)

#### What I want to do is this:

```
<div class="in-flex">
    <mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>
    <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

#### The style

```
.in-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I can't give to the children any kind of width, neither in percentages or rems or other, I need to have them fully responsive and managed in a way like flex does. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Solution:
It may help you. 
Add the breakpoint media query in css.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
   .in-flex{
     display: block !important;
   }
}
```